# Android  pass data from dialog to screen on which dialog pops up

Tags: android, dialog

I want to fill the edit text on my main screen via dialog. The dialog will pop up.user will enter the data (name or email) and the click ok. The name and email should be dispalyed on the screen on which the dialog poped up..

```
public class DialogActivity extends Activity 
{
/* Called when the activity is first created.*/
final Context context = this;
//private Button button;
String result;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.item);


        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(DialogActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.main);
        dialog.setTitle("I'm soo ");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();

        Button okButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(DialogActivity.this);
                    final EditText barFirst= (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edittext01);
                    final EditText barSecond= (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edittext02);
                    result = barFirst.getText().toString();

                    dialog.hide(); 

            }  
        });
      EditText tview = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cat_id);
        tview.setText(result);
        Toast.makeText(this, result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

my xml file has to `EditText` that want to display the data being entered in the dialog after the dialog is closed

Comment: And whats wrong with the code you have posted? You should remove the Try/Catch block as it is hiding any genuine errors

Comment: the problem is the data is not being send to the screen after ok buton on dialog is clicked...am i missing some thing?...

Comment: i have removed the try catch block. but still the data is not send to the screen after dialog didmis

Comment: So have you checked the result variable, do you receive the value? You should debug and tell us your exact issue

Comment: how will u make the dialog box to appear by button click  ?

Comment: when i run my code dialog appears.i enter the value in editetxt and click ok.dialog dismiss..im expecting it to now show the values on the screen (the value i entered in dialog) but when i click ok the scren reamain empty.no value is passing btw dialog to screen. this is the issue im not getting how to send value from dialog to screen

Comment: the dialog has to apper when the activity is called. so its doing that. now values from dialog are not gping on screen

Comment: oke now i changed my layout of screen to item.xml.........but still not passing data.

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.item);
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(DialogActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.main);

Comment: ///defined the textview after the onclicklistner of dialog

Comment: but no output.its not taking any thing

Comment: EditText tview = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cat_id);
            tview.setText(result);
            Toast.makeText(this, result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: i have edited my code but the editbox on xcreen is still empty it dose not show the string i enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public class DialogActivity extends Activity {

/* Called when the activity is first created.*/
   final Context context = this;
    //private Button button;
       String result;

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          setContentView(R.layout.main);




    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(DialogActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.main);
    dialog.setTitle("I'm soo ");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.show();

    Button okButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(DialogActivity.this);
                final EditText barFirst= (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edittext01);
                final EditText barSecond= (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edittext02);
                result = barFirst.getText().toString();

                dialog.dismiss(); 
    EditText tview = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cat_id);
    tview.setText(result);



        }  
    });
```